# Options for handling postbacks in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently the way I am handling postbacks in [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) is to grab the input variables using:

```
string username = "";

if (null != Request["username"])
     username = Request["username"].ToString();
```

I then would run a regex on the variable to ensure it was valid.

Is there any other method for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) does Request-To-Object mapping automatically, through [ModelBinders](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx). An older [article is here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx), under "Form Post and Model Binder Improvements", and there is [a video here](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/chopsticks/default.aspx?id=798).

Comment: Yes that is what I recall reading, but what if the page has more inputs in it that don't directly map to a particular object? Mix and match then?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the form inputs in your Action this way:

```
public ActionResult Create(string username)
{
  // use
}
```

but you need to set your Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "Create/{username}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "YourController", action = "Create", username = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Or you can use [ModelBinders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx)